# How do i fix this problem of caesar cipher in python?

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

```
wheel = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
wlen = len(wheel) - 1

c = input("Type a word: ").upper()
key = int(input("Key: "))

encrypted = ''


for x in c:
    f = wheel.find(x) + key 
    if x == " ":
        encrypted = encrypted + " "
    if f > wlen:
        f1 = f - wlen - 1
        encrypted = encrypted + wheel[f1] 
    if f < wlen:
        encrypted = encrypted + wheel[f]

print(encrypted)
```

This code isn't working and I can't find a reason why. I need help.

For example "I suck at coding" gives `"M DWYGO DEX DGSHMRK"`
There is this extra **D** in all the words that come after space. "M **D**WYGO **D**EX **D**GSHMRK"
Thank You.

Comment: Look at your `if`s. When the first one is true, does the second one also run? And the third? Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `elif`

```
if x == " ":
    encrypted = encrypted + " "
elif f > wlen:
    f1 = f - wlen - 1
    encrypted = encrypted + wheel[f1]
elif f < wlen:
    encrypted = encrypted + wheel[f]
```

Why :

When you have a space, the `find` returns -1, so adding the key you got `3`, so you enters in the first `if` as it's a space BUT also in the last if as `3<25` so  you add the `wheel[f]`  which is a `D`, with the `elif` you'll go only on one condition

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your condition checks, as multiple conditions evaluate to `True` at the same time which is not intended.

```
for x in c:
    f = wheel.find(x) + key 
    if x == " ":
        encrypted = encrypted + " "
    elif f > wlen:
        f1 = f - wlen - 1
        encrypted = encrypted + wheel[f1] 
    else:
        encrypted = encrypted + wheel[f]
```